# Gitlab-ci.yml deploy Angular project to Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Currently I am trying to host my Angular project in an Azure Linux VM but I don't know where to start with this. Do I need to install dependencies manually and use the gitlab-ci to automatically copy the build-files into a specific folder from the web server? Or is installing the dependencies (web server for example) a part of the gitlab-ci.yaml file?

I just find it hard to find to decide how to do this. What can I try?